# How do I access the field of an item in a generic arraylist of objects in java?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, field

For an assignment, I'm trying to write a method that searches through one of several ArrayLists (each containing different collections of objects) and returning the object that has a matching 'name' field to that specified. I can do so by implementing a function that searches over a pre-set arraylist '_content' of one kind of object like so:

```
public static Data findContent(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _content.size(); i++ ) {
            if (name.equals(((_content).get(i))._name)) {
                return ((_content).get(i));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And returns the first object with the matching name field or null if one could not be found.
I want to use generic types to have one method that can search over several different lists of different objects (Where each object in each list will have a 'name' field). How would I go about doing so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this as an approach as I haven't compiled it or anything I am also typing on a tablet so please excuse any minor typos I'll correct them if they are pointed out.  but....

In OO the recommended approach would be to encapsulate your objects so you wouldn't use fields directly you would use an accessor method.

```
public String Name (){
    return name;
}
```

You could then create an interface

```
public interface DataI {
    String getName ();
}
```

Your data object would then be

```
 public class Data implements DataI {
      private String name;

      public String getName (){
          return name;
      }

      public void  setName (String name){
          this.name = name;
      }
  }
```

Having done that your generic approach would be something like.

```
public static <T extends DataI> T findContent(String name, List<T> content) {
    for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++ ) {
        if (name.equals(((content).get(i)).getName())) {
            return ((content).get(i));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The string `<T extends DataI>` defines the generic type `T` for use within the method.

As T extends DataI only classes that implemented DataI will satisfy the constraint and these will all therefore have the getName () method required.

In certain circumstances you may need to change your list argument to `List<? extends T>`. Depending on what you want to do inside your method. There are discussions around on why this is which I will not go into here.

Comment: Your answer is more detailed than mine (+1). I initially had `List<? extends T>` in my answer, but then I realised that in this case it isn't any more general. The two signatures accept exactly the same things.

Comment: I think you would need the extends when you want to pass in an extra argument that is a Candidate for insertion in the list as well as the list itself.   I am not in front of an IDE at the moment so I cannot get the details on this and I can't remember which way it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You would first need an interface with a method `name`.

```
interface NamedThing {

    String name();
}
```

Then you could use a generic method

```
public static <T extends NamedThing> T find(Collection<T> collection, String name) {
    for (T t : collection)
        if (t.name().equals(name))
            return t;
    return null;
}
```

For simplicity I haven't bothered with any `null` checks in this answer.

If you are using Java 8, the method becomes a one-liner:

```
public static <T extends NamedThing> T find(Collection<T> collection, String name) {
    return collection.stream().filter(t->t.name().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8, I recommend to adopt `java.util.function.Function` for that purpose.

```
public static <T> T findContent(List<T> a, String name, java.util.function.Function<T, String> nameOf) {
  for (T e: a) {
    if (nameOf.apply(e).equals(name)) return e;
  }
  return null;
}
```

An usage, for example.

```
static class Data {
  private String name;
  public Data(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() { return name; }
}

// Assuming `import java.util.*` above.
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.err.println("result: "+ findContent(
    Arrays.asList(
      new Data("a"),
      new Data("b"),
      new Data("c")
    ),
    "b",
    Data::getName // Passing an accessor to Data#name as a lambda expression
  ));
}
```

From the viewpoint of "Design Patterns", the passed lambda expression to `nameOf` at #3 can be considered an "Adapter" to get a name from a certain class `T`. the "Adapter Pattern" is useful when a class isn't open to modification, to adapt to an existing module.

Sorry for my poor English.